# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS software center crashed

Tags: software-center

The software center crashed, an error message showing `the package pkiclient-full:i386 needs to be reinstalled`. How to solve this problem? I tried to re install the same but not worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open Software Center and re- install an application](http://askubuntu.com/questions/777643/cannot-open-software-center-and-re-install-an-application)